# Yii2 REST API fields (user?fields=id) does not work

Tags: rest, yii2

I've got the REST API working with the user table provided in the base migration.  I can "GET /users" just fine, but according to the docs, I should also be able to "GET /users?fields=id" and receive a response limited to the id fields.

But instead I get the full result set.

Comment: Check if the attribute with the name `id ` really exists (maybe it's named differently). Also show how you overrided `fields()` method (If you did).

Comment: Yes, id is a valid field.  When I do an index or view, it is there.  I've not overridden fields().

Answer (score 0):

Under the topic [Fields](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#fields) in Yii2 Guide it says;

```
// only returns field id and email, provided they are declared in fields()
http://localhost/users?fields=id,email
```

so you have to override the `fields()` function to get the expected result.

```
// explicitly list every field, best used when you want to make sure the changes
// in your DB table or model attributes do not cause your field changes (to keep API backward compatibility).
public function fields()
{
    return [
        // field name is the same as the attribute name
        'id',
        // field name is "email", the corresponding attribute name is "email_address"
        'email' => 'email_address',
        // field name is "name", its value is defined by a PHP callback
        'name' => function ($model) {
            return $model->first_name . ' ' . $model->last_name;
        },
    ];
}
```

Comment: Quote from documentation to `fields()` (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#fields%28%29-detail) method: "The default implementation of this method returns attributes() indexed by the same attribute names." So it should work without overriding `fields` since attribute `id` is presented in model.